Third party javascript libraries and keeping them up to date
So our org uses a multitude of third party javascript libraries; for example jquery and usually stored as a static resource.
One problem is sometimes these are used in externally facing components, so those libraries need to be kept up to date. The problem is knowing which ones are out of date.
I was looking at using Dependabot in github, other groups use it to keep up with dependencies....except it doesn't seem to 'just work' out of the box for salesforce and i've been unable to find anyone who's configured it to work with a salesforce git repo. So I'm wondering if anyone here has found any open source solutions to simply alerting devs/admins when their third party libraries hosted as static resources (or even the ones that use other methods such as         apex:includeScript) are behind on versions.
Right now I'm considering a shared doc that lists the current version numbers and a RSS feed/email alert from that hits our devs whenever there's a new version of said libraries...then the manual work of updating the version but also that doc. I'm simply wondering if anyone has come across better solutions.

I think you can just npm install the things you need to the same Salesforce repository and let NPM keep track of the libraries. I haven't tried this myself, but I believe it is an option (it is definitely what I would be trying as first resource).

Would that work in terms of noticing a static resource that's version x is behind the latest version? From a technical perspective i'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how that would actually function.

Of course not, because the static resources are not read by NPM. You would still have to update the static resources manually. The workflow here would be to let NPM inform you of which dependencies need to be updated, and then you update them with NPM and copy the libraries to the static resources. How you do that is up to you. You could have bash script to update them, for example (assuming the library allows you to just copy the js file to the static resources folder).

I gotcha...sort of. I get i would have to update the static resource manually. But how would NPM know that static resource x is an out of date version of jquery. Is the suggestion i use NPM install  which is what i need then update the existing versions. In the future NPM would let me know if it's out of date?

npm wouldn't know that the static resource is out of date. It would know that the package you added through npm as a dependency. But then you would need to update the static resource manually. One thing to take into consideration is that npm doesn't actively look for updates, so you have to run some update command from npm from time to time on your own.
